# How to show GUI button once the first person collides with an object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am creating an educational virtual walk through for kids, and I have a small problem on how to show a button once my first person collides in a cube/object.

Here is my code:

```
#pragma strict
var timer : int;
var move : GUI;

function Start () {

}

timer = Time.deltaTime;

function OnCollisionEnter (obj: Collision) {
    if (obj.collider.name == "Cube")
    {
        GUI.Button(Rect(0,0,200,100), 'Button');
    }
}
```

Comment: It even works fine and show button right now? I thought GUI components could be called just inside OnGUI function or Unity may throws an exception...

Comment: Still, no button shows. I tried many method but I am so disappointed @Frohlich By the way, thank you

Comment: Which version of Unity do you use? `> 5` or `< 5`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much of Unity Script and don't really know if your code works this way it is or maybe you paste a little different that it already is on your component so I'll write an approach in C# but you can easily adjust for US:

```
public bool showButton = false
public Rect buttonRect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 100);

void OnGUI() {
    if(show) {
        if(GUI.Button(buttonRect, "Button") {
            // do what you need here...
            show = false; //after click and do what you need hide the button again
        }
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        show = true;
    }
}
```

*Disable any trigger on your colliders, I think if OnTrigger enters OnCollisionEnter will never be called (you can easily debug it to grant that your OnCollisionEnter is being called)...*

**note:** I've adjusted to get "Player" tag so you need to attach it on your Cube, if you want to use it on your player just put on your cube some tag that you want to test for (I didn't use name because I don't really know how unity will treat it, usually it is used tags to do this kind of collision tests)...

**ps:** I can't test it right now so if it still throws errors please paste them here.

Comment: There are some errors in this code. I try to fixed it but then nothing happen @Frohlich

Comment: probably there are many errors I write right here and didn't test, what errors it present you? Note that I already realized some of them and correct it to take "Player"'s tag so you'll need to attach it on your cube not on your player...